# How to make \text_uppercase:n in section's argument bookmark compliant?

Tags: expansion, expl3, bookmarks, capitalization

Thanks to recent revision of the coverage of `UTF-8` input for `pdfTeX` and accents with the `expl3` (see updated answer of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286703/18401), the following code works nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}        % Over-ridden by fontspec for XeTeX/LuaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Over-ridden by fontspec for XeTeX/LuaTeX
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % This bails out for XeTeX/LuaTeX
\ifnum 0%
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion 1\fi
  \ifdefined\directlua    1\fi
  >0 %
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\usepackage{xparse}

% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{unicode}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \ExplUpperCase { m } { \text_uppercase:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\section{\ExplUpperCase{aäa}}

\section{\text_uppercase:n{aäa}}

% \section{\ExplUpperCase{a\"aa}}

% \section{\text_uppercase:n{a\"aa}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, if `hyperref` is loaded:

1. whatever the engine used, `\"a` cannot be used because “Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\"' on input line [...]”,
2. if the engine used is:

   1. `pdf(La)TeX`, the bookmarks are wrong regardless (but differently) of the `\hypersetup{unicode}` use,
   2. `xe(La)TeX`, the bookmarks are right regardless of `\hypersetup{unicode}` use,
   3. `lua(La)TeX`, the bookmarks are:

      - right if `\hypersetup{unicode}` is used,
      - wrong if `\hypersetup{unicode}` is *not* used.

Do you know how to make the bookmarks right in all the cases?

Comment: You have to expand `\tl_upper_case:n` before feeding it to section, such that `hyperref` sees the bare uppercase characters.  Try for instance `\exp_args:Nx \section { \tl_upper_case:n { aäa } }`.

Comment: This all looks to be working for me with an up-to-date `expl3`: can you re-check?

Comment: @JosephWright What do you mean by "up-to-date"? Here, with a fresh TL 2016, and `expl3-code.tex 2016/05/18 v6512`, that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Handling LuaTeX with `hyperref` and lacking the `unicode` option is going to be tricky, but the other cases can all be covered by forcing expansion. You have to remember that `hyperref` is seeing not the result of the case changing but the input, otherwise. Something like

```
\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\section{sO{}m}{%
  \begingroup
    \protected@edef\x{%
      \endgroup
        \noexpand\oldsection
        \IfNoValueT#1{*}%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
        \else
          [\unexpanded{#2}]%
        \fi
        {#3}%
    }%
  \x
}
\makeatother
```

will make `\section` expand the mandatory argument but should be 'safe' with LaTeX2e robust commands.